Performance implications of INSERT INTO...SELECT :NEW.FIELD FROM DUMMY
Let's say we have a table BASE in a HANA:
CREATE COLUMN TABLE BASE
("CLIENT" NVARCHAR(3) DEFAULT '000' NOT NULL ,
 "KEY" DECIMAL(21,7) CS_FIXED DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
 "VALUE_FIELD" NVARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "BASE~0" PRIMARY KEY ("CLIENT", "KEY"));

Then we create a log table to capture keys of changed records from the BASE table:
CREATE COLUMN TABLE LOG_TABLE
("CLIENT" NVARCHAR(3) DEFAULT '000' NOT NULL ,
 "KEY" DECIMAL(21,7) CS_FIXED DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
 "LOG_TIMESTAMP" DECIMAL(21,7) CS_FIXED DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
 "DB_OPERATION" NVARCHAR(1) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "LOG_TABLE~0" PRIMARY KEY ("CLIENT", "KEY", "LOG_TIMESTAMP"));

Here we don't care about value fields, only about keys. I have a trigger code generator depending on the necessity to log changes in specific clients or in all clients. For now, i came up with this solution:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "trg_BASE_D"
AFTER DELETE ON "BASE"
REFERENCING OLD ROW AS R
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "LOG_TABLE" (CLIENT, KEY, LOG_TIMESTAMP, DB_OPERATION)
  SELECT :R.CLIENT, :R.KEY, TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_UTCTIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF7')), 'D'
  FROM DUMMY
  WHERE :R.CLIENT IN ('010', '020');
END;

Of course, similar triggers are created for Insert and Update.
Question: does this solution of selecting from dummy have any advantage over more explicit IF solution? That is, do we have any performance implications when using dummy and when using IF?
For comparison:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "trg_BASE_D_IF"
AFTER DELETE ON "BASE"
REFERENCING OLD ROW AS R
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :R.CLIENT = '010' OR :R.CLIENT = '020' THEN
    INSERT INTO "LOG_TABLE" (CLIENT, KEY, LOG_TIMESTAMP, DB_OPERATION)
    VALUES (:R.CLIENT, :R.KEY, TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_UTCTIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF7')), 'D');
  END IF;
END;

IF automatically results in making SQL script sequential but, at the same time, it uses values directly, without using dummy. Besides, there is nothing here to parallelise as the trigger is ROW-based; WHERE solution doesn't use IF but selects from dummy. How will it impact the trigger performance? Or there will be no difference at all, and it comes down to personal preferences in this case? I prefer a WHERE-based solution as it's easier to generate programmatically; however, both are quite easy to implement, so i'm open to either.
Sorry, i don't have access to an actual HANA DB to run performance tests - i only generate trigger code in ABAP...

Guessing about how your workload will perform with either option is pointless - the proof is in the pudding and only measuring the differences in runtime for your workload will provide the answer to the question "which option is better"?
However, generally: once you're doing row-level triggers, you're working row-by-row anyhow - no need to worry about code turning "sequential".
Generally, using FROM DUMMY is rather expensive and I would recommend to avoid it (but also: it's just plain ugly).

Thanks, @LarsBr. - that's what i wanted to hear (: As i'm 99.9% an ABAP developer, i don't know quite well what is costly/ugly and what is not ==> hence the question. I'll change it in favour of IFs. As for row vs statement, i'm aware of the difference. What i don't clearly understand is the benefit of one over the other. Mainly, statement level triggers are always fired; row level, only when rows are really impacted. As SAP never updates large volumes in a single statement (max would be hundreds or thousands, or even a single record), then having row level seems more beneficial.

@LarsBr. Please see my comments to Jonas's answer - modify/insert/update .. from table produces lots of individual transactions compared to update...set...where. Doesn't that make statement level triggers useless? Of course, pudding will prove which is better (: but, maybe, you (or others) had experience with this in SAP already.

@ro4dRunErr you've already noticed how different DBMS (and different statements!) lead to very different behaviour of the ABAP Kernel in regards to the statements created. That should be a strong indicator for that making the sort of implementation detail decisions without testing and definition of the assumptions will not result in an informed decision.
E.g. one major difference of FOR EVERY ROW and ... STATEMENT is the implicit locking. Does that matter for what you are building? I'd recommed implementing what's obvious to you and address issues when you understand them better.

@LarsBr. Can you please help with implicit locking? In my case, triggers are insert-only, with key that includes the full key of the original record + event timestamp, which always provides a unique key (provided timestamps have high enough resolution or changes to the same record don't happen at rate of 10s of 1000s per second). In such case FOR ALL ENTRIES shouldn't suffer performance degradation from the implicit locking. Am i missing something? E.g., when locking is done by pages, not by rows, and neighbouring keys are inserted, such as document items modified in bulk?

This topic extends well beyond the immediate question posted. There are documentation, SAP notes, online resources and books available covering the topic. The comments section here is not the right place to cover it.

Sorry, won't comment anymore.

If I had to guess I would assume that the procedural IF variant is better, as it does not need to prepare and execute a query - but the difference is likely small and probably smaller than other potential effects.
What I would rather worry about are bulk inserts into your table with many rows. There looping and performing a singular insert for each row might slow things down significantly. There I guess using the FOR EACH STATEMENT variant with OLD TABLE might be better as the insert in the log table can be done in bulk:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "trg_BASE_D"
AFTER DELETE ON "BASE"
REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS R
FOR EACH STATEMENT
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "LOG_TABLE" (CLIENT, KEY, LOG_TIMESTAMP, DB_OPERATION)
  SELECT CLIENT, KEY, TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_UTCTIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF7')), 'D'
  FROM :R
  WHERE CLIENT IN ('010', '020');
END;


Thanks. I was thinking about pros and cons of for each row myself. As this is an SAP system, there won't be thousands of transactions per second. Exception is batch processes which may produce a lot of documents/statements/etc. but that happens once per specific period, and SAP kernel still uses individual inserts translating ABAP's for all entries or insert...from table, so for each statement may not be efficient as each statement will contain only 1 record... On the other hand, for each statement is always triggered irrespective whether needed or not.

Another point in support of the non-procedural approach is that, because the trigger has a static SQL statement, it should be already compiled and prepared. Only query execution is needed, but that's true for the INSERT statement anyway in both approaches. I may be wrong - will gladly accept corrections to my thinking (:

„and SAP kernel still uses individual inserts translating ABAP's insert … from table - I highly doubt that, do you have any source for that?

A DML statement is conceptually quite different from a query. If the IF statement evaluates to false, no INSERT happens, whereas the other variant always has to evaluate the select query.

Hi @Jonas, yes, i have a proof of that, though it's indirect. First of all, i noticed that things like select..for all entries are translated differently on different databases, e.g., in some cases a union is produced and used in a join (MS SQL); in other cases, a number of conditions joined with OR in where... As for the modify .. from table which inserts records, i captured such records with a trigger. I tested 2 cases - creating an FI document with a BAPI and directly updating BKPF table in bulk. In all cases, timestamps of each row was different.

...However, when i wrote something like update bkpf set... WHERE, instead of from table, the timestamp of all updated records was the same. Not a solid proof, but, at least, hints at that.

As for selects, i noticed such a behaviour long time ago working with execution plan analysers in both SAP and DB tools (MS SQL management console). I don't remember what HANA-based kernel produces, but it can't differ much from what the kernel does on other databases.
Of course, it's not documented anywhere as it's SAP kernel which is DB-specific. SAP documents open SQL and HANA DB SQL, but never how one becomes the other - not publicly, at least. You can test it if you have 2 or more different databases at hand.
And that's why for all entries isn't a good thing (:

Interesting observations - Only found https://me.sap.com/notes/2178105 which documents that for older DB2 versions MERGE is done row-by-row, whereas for newer versions it is done in bulk. Could not find any Notes for HDB though ...
